# #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't access to PHPMyAdmin. when i want to go there, i got this error:

> #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

I googled this error but it don't clear.

I try to know that which port is open by this code :

```
pgrep mysql
```

two ports are open when mysql is running.

I want to access to PHPMyAdmin in my localhost. I am using Ubuntu OS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ubuntu, by default `mysql` is not listening to TCP/IP connections. It just uses a local socket.

The current local socket is configured in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` . If you open this file, you should find something similar to:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

What you should do is just to open `PHPMyAdmin`'s config file (`config.inc.php`) and change the socket address. Maybe there's no local socket configuration on your PHPMyAdmin, or maybe it is different. This file should contain a line like (of course, adapt the address to what you found on `my.cnf`):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps just to run the mysql server after crash.

** Worked on wamp server **

1. Check the `{System name}.err` file inside your mysql data directory.
2. From the log find out the databases causing issues
3. Cut them out from the data directory (keep in some safe places).
4. Start mysql service

Answer (score 0):

go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc 
edit host 
add 127.0.0.1 localhost 
and restart server refrance 
[check ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382251/2002-the-server-is-not-responding-or-the-local-mysql-servers-socket-is-not/48382252#48382252)

Answer (score -4):

This means that mysql server is not started.
This is very simply if you are using wamp left click the wampserver icon then mysql then services then install service after that restart wamp and the problem is solved

Comment: The question states that `mysql` is running and especially that it is about **Ubuntu**. `WAMP` is windows only